# ¿Cómo comparar 2 columnas de tablas diferentes en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Parece la pregunta mas genérica posible y un duplicado pero consultando otras respuestas nada se adecua a el resultado que quiero, resulta que tengo que hacer una consulta donde selecciono los usuarios donde el campo **id_cliente** de la tabla usuarios sea diferente al **id_cliente** de la tabla clientes a que me refiero:

Tengo 2 tablas

> Tabla 1 : usuario
>
> Tabla 2 : clientes
>
> en la tabla usuarios hay un campo llamado **id_cliente**
>
> en la tabla clientes hay un campo llamado **id_cliente**

Y necesito comparar que el **id_cliente** de la tabla usuarios sea diferente al **id_cliente** de la tabla clientes

Explicándome mejor en mi aplicación Android tengo un registro de usuario, cuando el usuario ingresa dicho usuario se registra como cliente en la tabla clientes, además este usuario puede agregar mas "usuarios" digamos que el usuario principal agrega mas usuarios, entonces yo tengo un `Recycler` donde obtengo todos los usuarios que agrego el usuario principal sin embargo como la consulta la hago a la tabla clientes (que es donde se inserto el usuario principal) también me trae dicho usuario principal entonces yo quiero que me muestre solo los usuarios que agrego el usuario principal pero no quiero que me muestre el usuario principal.

Por esa razón es que estoy tratando de validar que me consulte nada mas los usuarios con el **id_cliente** de clientes que sea diferente del **id_cliente** de usuarios al lograr la validación la consulta solo me traería los usuarios que agrego el usuario principal mas no el usuario principal.

A continuación tratare de explicarlo de la manera mas grafica posible:

[image: Tabla usuarios]

En un principio agrego mi usuario principal

[image: Tabla clientes]

Entonces el usuario Marcela se inserto en la tabla clientes como cliente (Nótese que el **id__cliente** de la tabla clientes es el mismo que el **id_cliente** de la tabla usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora marcela agrego un usuario en la tabla clientes (Nótese que el **id_usuario** del usuario que agrego marcela es el mismo que el de marcela debido a que fue ella quien agrego el usuario.

Ahora viene la parte donde quiero obtener el usuario que agrego marcela pero no quiero obtener a marcela. para eso hice la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$sql = "SELECT 
cli.nombre_cliente
FROM clientes cli
LEFT JOIN usuarios us
on cli.id_cliente != us.id_cliente";
        
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

$datos = array();

while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
}

echo json_encode(array("Clientes" => $datos));

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Esa seria la consulta que obtendría en Android studio para obtener los clientes que sean diferentes al **id_cliente** de usuarios. pero lo que obtengo son todos los usuarios de la tabla clientes ya hice diferentes inner y el resultado es el mismo.

Disculpen la extensa explicación pero quería que quedara bastante clara la pregunta, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: En pocas palabras, lo que requieres es traer todos los clientes que marcela(usuario principal) agregó, para eso solo requieres anexar a tu consulta ya establecida una serie de condiciones para cumplir a cabalidad lo que deseas y con el menor costo posible en cuanto a la BD.

Comment: Prueba con `SELECT c.* FROM clientes c INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_usuario = c.id_usuario AND u.id_cliente <> c.id_cliente`

Comment: SELECT 
cli.nombre_cliente
FROM clientes cli
LEFT JOIN usuarios us
on cli.id_cliente == us.id_cliente
and us.id_usuario = ? // Aqui se filtra por el id_usuario del usuario principal
and cli.id_cliente != ? // Aqui se filtra por el id_cliente que sea diferente al del usuario principal

Prueba realizar la consulta de esta manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE cliente.id NOT IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(usuario.id_cliente) FROM usuario );

básicamente, `GROUP_CONCAT(usuario.id_cliente)` genera una lista con todos los id_cliente, luego el `NOT IN` excluye esos id contenidos en la lista.

Comment: Realmente no recomendaría hacerlo de esta manera, la consulta que stás generando esmuy costosa, pudiendo hacerse la consulta de una manera mejor